# EC2 Cloud Formation - Error Message

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

## This is my cloudFormation template.

Description: Create a variable number of EC2 instance resources.

**Parameters:**

```
  InstanceCount:
    Description: Number of EC2 instances (must be between 1 and 3).
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 3
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a number between 1 and 3.
    Description: launch EC2 instances.
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance

InstanceType:
    Description: Launch EC2 instances.
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues: [ t2.micro ]

Conditions:
  Launch1: !Equals [1, 1]
  Launch2: !Not [!Equals [1, !Ref InstanceCount]]
  Launch3: !Or
  - !Not [!Equals [1, !Ref InstanceCount]]
  - !Not [!Equals [2, !Ref InstanceCount]]


**Resources:**

Instance1:
    Condition: Launch1
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2

Instance2:
    Condition: Launch2
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2

Instance3:
    Condition: Launch3
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2
```

### Error Message

Template contains errors.: Invalid template property or properties [InstanceType]

## Can someone please help me to find why am I getting this error?

Thank you

Comment: You should post the complete properly formatted template. These type errors are formatting errors.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I'm able to create a stack with the same template https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/0a9112e2afb337990388d78bef031454

Answer (score 0):

If you observe closely, the indentation of the template was messed up at `InstanceType` after the `InstanceCount`. Fix it as mentioned below and you should be good to go.

```
  InstanceCount:
      Description: Number of EC2 instances (must be between 1 and 3).
      Type: Number
      Default: 1
      MinValue: 1
      MaxValue: 3
      ConstraintDescription: Must be a number between 1 and 3.
      Description: launch EC2 instances.
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance

  InstanceType:
      Description: Launch EC2 instances.
      Type: String
      Default: t2.micro
      AllowedValues: [ t2.micro ]
```

Hope this helps.